# Mostrar carpetas y archivos LARAVEL

Tags: laravel-7

Llevo días intentando buscar y aplicar lógica para conseguir mostrar en mi vista (estilo árbol de directorios) las carpetas y archivos de mi public en Laravel a cada usuario.

Me gustaría que me orientaran un poco por donde puedo empezar a buscar, llevo ya muchas horas buscando y no veo nada.

El objetivo es obtener un resultado parecido a este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el proyecto, cada cliente sube archivos a su plataforma, que eso ya lo tengo funcionando.

En carpeta public / storage tengo un archivo llamado documentos. El orden de creación para cada cliente es 1º creamos una carpeta con ID del cliente 2º creamos carpeta del año, 3º creamos carpeta del mes y dentro de esa carpeta se guardan los archivos que el cliente sube (asi los tengo ordenado por cliente, año mes).

```
public function guardar(Request $request)
{

    $validatedData = $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'unique:contabilizar,ruta',
        'idfigura' => 'required'

    ]);
    $idfigura = request('idfigura');

    //pillamos el file
    $image = $request->file('file');

    if($image){
    //calculamos el tamaño
    $imagesize = filesize($image);

    //vemos quien es el que lo sube, es decir quien esta logeado
    $logeado = Auth::User()->id;

    //cargamos la figura
    $figura = Figura::FindOrFail($idfigura);
    //nombre con peso
    $imageName = $imagesize.'--'.$image->getClientOriginalName();

    $ano = date("Y");
    setlocale(LC_TIME, "spanish");
    $mes = strftime("%B");

    Storage::putFileAs('/public/documentos/' . $figura->id . '/'. $ano . '/' . $mes  . '/', $image, $imageName);



    $a = Contabilizar::where('ruta', $imageName)->count();

        if($a == 0){
            $contabilizar = new Contabilizar();
            $contabilizar->figura_id = $idfigura;
            $contabilizar->ruta = $imageName;
            $contabilizar->tipo_documento_id = 1;
            $contabilizar->estado_documento_id = 1;
            $contabilizar->asesor_id = $figura->asesor_id;
            $contabilizar->nombre_documento = $imageName;
            $contabilizar->id_subido = $logeado;
            $contabilizar->save();

        }

    }
```

El guardado el correcto, en la base de datos almaceno la informacion solo del nombre de la imagen , eso no es lo que me preocupa.

En un atabla el cliente si puede ver todos sus archivos subidos, en orden de fecha pero claro, TODOS.

```
<td><a target="_blank" href="/storage/documentos/{{ $figura->id }}/{{ date('Y', strtotime($conta->created_at)) }}/{{ strftime('%B', strtotime($conta->created_at)) }}/{{ $conta->nombre_documento }}"> {{ $conta->nombre_documento}}</a></td>
```

Una vez tengo ya todo guardado y lo muestro de forma individual, lo que necesito es eso mismo, obtener un arbol como el que muestro en la imagen inicial ordenado por id, año, carpetas, meses.

He conseguido obtener el año de la ruta del cliente de la siguiente manera en el controlador.

```
 $directory = public_path();
    $files = Storage::Directories('/public/documentos/'.$id_figura);
    $ultimo1 = basename($files);
```

Me ofrece 2020.

Si pongo allDIrectories:

public/documentos/11/2020 public/documentos/11/2020/octubre

LA EXTRUCTURA de la ruta y los archivos siempre es la misma.

public_pacth / documentos / {id del cliente} / año {sacado del created_at}/ mes / nombre_del_documento

La idea, de nuevo es que el cliente pinche en documentos subidos y vea los años, por ejemplo:

2020
2021

Pinche en 2020 y se genere el arbol con los meses que tenga

2020
--Octubre
--Noviembre

Y cuando pinche en cada mes, vea los archivos subidos por nombre

2020
--Octubre
--Noviembre
---- nombre archivo.jpg

Esta ruta de ejemplo sería

pubic_patch/documentos/IDcliente(7 por ejemplo)/2020/noviembre/nombrearchivo.jpg

Comment: En la documentación de Laravel, siempre. [File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem), [Blade Templates](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade)

Comment: Llevo ya 5 dias intentadolo pero no hay manera, no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Cada cliente tiene su propia carpeta ID/MES/fichero que guardo la ruta en bbdd y en storage, y me devuelve un array con todo sin orden, por ejemplo:

7/octubre/dfdfdf.jpg
7/noviembre/sdfsdfsd.jpg
7/noviembre/sdfsdfsd222.jpg

La idea es ordenarlo con ul y li para que el cliente pueda acceder a sus archivos de forma ordenada pro año, meses

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que dices que has intentado, y que resultado te devuelve en cada caso (supongo que si llevas 5 días intentándo tendrás bastante material), así si alguien se toma el trabajo de escribir una respuesta, no le digas que eso ya lo intentaste y no funciona ¿Probaste iterar sobre ese array que mencionas haciendo un `explode` por ejemplo?...

Comment: También sería útil que agregues a la pregunta la estructura de directorios es conocida o no, por ejemplo, no es lo mismo si ya sabes que la estructura será `/id_cliente/mes/archivo.ext`, que si la estructura tendrá un número variable de subdirectorios. También qué es lo que esperas obtener, ¿un array asociativo multidimensional te serviría?

Comment: He editado la pregunta con eso que me pides

Answer (score 1):

Esta respuesta está exclusivamente basada en la estructura de directorios que tengas en el disco, y no tiene en cuenta lo que hayas guardado en la base de datos.

Para este ejemplo usé esta estructura de directorios/archivos:

```
tu_proyecto/storage/app/public/documentos
    11/
        2019/
            noviembre/
                archivo_1.txt
                archivo_2.txt
            octubre/
                archivo_1.txt
                archivo_2.txt
        2020/
            noviembre/
                archivo_1.txt
                archivo_2.txt
            octubre
                archivo_1.txt
                archivo_2.txt
    12/
        2019/
            noviembre/
                archivo_1.txt
                archivo_2.txt
            octubre/
                archivo_1.txt
                archivo_2.txt
        2020/
            noviembre/
                archivo_1.txt
                archivo_2.txt
            octubre
                archivo_1.txt
                archivo_2.txt
```

En tu controlador puedes hacer algo así (explico la lógica con comentarios en el código):

```
// directorio del cliente en `/storage/app/public`
$id_figura = 11;
// Obtienes los subdirectorios que están dentro del directorio del cliente
$directorios_del_cliente = Storage::directories("/public/documentos/{$id_figura}");
// creas un array vacío para ir llenándolo con los elementos año/mes/archivos
$tree_array = [];

// iteras sobre los directorios obtenidos
foreach ($directorios_del_cliente as $directorio_del_ano) {
    // haciendo un explode, separas el string en un array con cada directorio.
    $temp_array = explode('/', $directorio_del_ano);
    // obtienes el último elemento (el año).
    $year = end( $temp_array );
    // Obtienes los subdirectorios que están dentro del directorio del año
    $subdirectorios_del_ano = Storage::directories("/public/documentos/$id_figura/$year");
    foreach ($subdirectorios_del_ano as $directorio_del_mes) {
        $temp_array = explode('/', $directorio_del_mes);
        // obtienes el último elemento (el mes).
        $month = end( $temp_array );
        // Obtienes los archivos que están dentro del directorio del mes
        $archivos_del_mes = Storage::files($directorio_del_mes);
        foreach ($archivos_del_mes as $archivo_del_mes) {
            $temp_array = explode('/', $archivo_del_mes);
            // obtienes el último elemento (el nombre del archivo).
            $filename = end( $temp_array );
            // obtienes la url que corresponde a ese archivo.
            $url = Storage::url($archivo_del_mes);
            // guardas en tu array el nombre y la url del archivo, 
            // haciendo que el array sea multidimensional por año y mes.
            $tree_array[$year][$month][] = [
                'filename' => $filename,
                'url' => $url
            ];
        }
    }
}

// devuelves la vista pasándole el array creado.
return view('test', ['tree_array' => $tree_array]);
```

Luego en la vista simplemente iteras sobre las múltiples dimensiones del array que creaste en el controlador:

```
@foreach($tree_array as $year => $months)
    <ul>
        <li>
            {{$year}}
            @foreach($months as $month => $files)
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        {{$month}}
                        @foreach($files as $file)
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{$file['url']}}">{{$file['filename']}}</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        @endforeach
                    </li>
                </ul>
            @endforeach
        </li>
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Resultado logrado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]